# 'short name' for iOS apps possible?

Tags: ios, truncation

I'd like to give my app one name for the App Store and one name that appears on the device, as app names that are too long are truncated with '…' on the device but not the store. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to have a long name for the app store and then a short name under the icon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11817190/how-to-have-a-long-name-for-the-app-store-and-then-a-short-name-under-the-icon)

Comment: This question came before that one…

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The app name you specify in Xcode as the name of your project is the one that will appear on the device. The name in the app store is something you set later when you set up your project on iTunes Connect.

To change your homescreen app name, you can change the Bundle Display Name in your info.plist as Shubhank suggests, or you can just rename your project by clicking twice (two separate clicks - not a double-click) on the project name in the left hand sidebar of Xcode.

Comment: Thanks! I did suspect it may be a case of Xcode for app and iTunes connect for store, but I thought I should be sure and couldn't find any mentions of it.

Comment: Sorry Shubhank, I felt Nick's answer was more complete!

Answer (score 9):

Yes..your app can have different name on device and on App store..

Naming your app on app store is kind of basic for an iOS developer.so i won't dive into that..

For on your device....in your project ..in your info.plist change the **Bundle Display Name** to what you want.