# How to have a long name for the app store and then a short name under the icon?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, app-store

How can I have a long name for the app in the app store and then a shortened name under the icon once it's downloaded? Is it possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When creating a new app in iTunes Connect:

[image]

Then in your apps info.plist file:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The App Store name is set in [iTunes Connect](http://itunesconnect.apple.com) when you actually submit your app. The one on the home screen is the one you set in your Info.plist, so you can easily use two different names.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the name of the app for `AppStore` in `itunesconnect`. And the name of the app that will be visible for the user on his/her device can be set in the `info.plist` file of the app. If I remember correctly it was `Bundle Name`, but I can be wrong. Don't have a Mac nearby at the moment

Answer (score 1):

The long name is set by iTunesConnect; the short name is set in the build settings under "Product Name".